# Repaining listfield on editfield change Input

Tags: list, blackberry, repaint

I am using Google place API in my application for searching location. When user input text in edit field then the API called and resulted output will shown in a list.

I implemented it successfully but the problem is that each time edit field text changes, the list is not repainting and output is added to the **end** of the list. I want every time the text changes in the edit text field, the list must remove its previous content that are invalid.

This can be seen in pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

For Implementing this, I have written this code:

```java
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
/**
 * Creates a new MyScreen object
 */
private Vector _listElements;
ListField list;
JSONObject[] jsonobject;
EditField editfield;
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=";
String[] locationName;
VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager();

public MyScreen() {
    ButtonField search = new ButtonField("Search");
    _listElements = new Vector();
    list = new ListField();
    ListCallback _callback = new ListCallback(this);

    // Set the displayed title of the screen
    setTitle("Search Edit Field");
    editfield = new EditField();
    editfield.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    list.invalidate();
                    createField();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    list.setCallback(_callback);
    add(editfield);

    add(new SeparatorField());

    verticalFieldManager.add(list);
    add(verticalFieldManager);

}

protected void createField() {
    ShowList();
    reloadList();

}

private void reloadList() {

    list.setSize(_listElements.size());

}

class ListCallback implements ListFieldCallback {
    MyScreen listDemoScreen;

    public ListCallback(MyScreen listDemoScreen) {
        this.listDemoScreen = listDemoScreen;

    }

    public void drawListRow(ListField list, Graphics g, int index, int y,
            int w) {

        String text = (String) _listElements.elementAt(index);
        list.setRowHeight(getFont().getHeight());

        g.drawText(text, 0, y, 0, -1);
    }

    public Object get(ListField list, int index) {
        return _listElements.elementAt(index);
    }

    public int indexOfList(ListField list, String prefix, int string) {
        return _listElements.indexOf(prefix, string);
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField list) {
        return Display.getWidth();
    }

}

protected void ShowList() {
    HttpConnection httpConn;

    InputStream in;
    ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
    ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
    String response;
    String fieldText = editfield.getText();
    connDesc = connFact.getConnection(url + fieldText
            + "%@&sensor=true&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            + ConnectionType.getConnectionType());
    if (connDesc != null) {
        httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();
        try {
            int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.openInputStream();
                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                int read = -1;
                while ((read = in.read()) != -1)
                    buf.append((char) read);

                response = buf.toString();
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray ar = object.getJSONArray("predictions");
                    jsonobject = new JSONObject[ar.length()];
                    locationName = new String[ar.length()];
                    list.invalidate();
                    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {
                        jsonobject[i] = ar.getJSONObject(i);

                        _listElements.addElement(jsonobject[i]
                                .getString("description"));

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Dialog.alert("Connection not succeded");
    }
}

protected boolean onSavePrompt() {
    return true;
    }
}
```

**Update and Solution:**

only modify this and this rest is working fine.  As Peter Suggests, we can also put a `Thread.sleep(time);` in order to get the UI not blocked:

```java
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      _listElements.removeAllElements();
        createField();
    }
});
```

Comment: Solution as proposed, which invokes createField() on the Event Thread, will most likely result in with Application Not Responding Exceptions.  This will be caused by running the networking processing in ShowList(), which createField() invokes, also on the Event Thread.

Comment: @Peter : Can you explain which points you are indicating. As this is hard to understand for me the text you written.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is simply that you do not clear the _listElements Vector when you request more data.  So _listElements just gets bigger.

However there is a bigger problem here and that is that your code appears to be running networking operations on the Event Thread.  What your should do in your changeListener. is start a Thread that requests the data, then repopulate the ListField when this tread gets data.

As a result of this change, the UI will not be blocked, and the List updates will become asynchronous, so your user could in fact enter another character into the EditField before the first Thread response comes back.  To prevent this looking silly, you could delay the Thread processing for a fraction of second to see if another character is entered, and/or you could make sure that the EditField content was still the same as the requested characters before you repopulate it.

I personally prefer this asynchronous approach, but if it bothers you, you could put a 'please wait - loading' type screen to block the user until the response comes back.

**Update**

Remember that if you start a background Thread, you need to get back onto the Event Thread to do Ui Processing.  Typically this is done simply by including your UI code within the run method of a Runnable that is invoked later, for example:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // Ui Code in here 
  }
});
```

You should only put Ui Updating code in the runnable.  Networking processing, or any other blocking action, should NOT be included.

Comment: I implemented something like this  new Thread(){
       public void run(){
        try {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
         createField();
       }
     }.start();
   }  but exception generated everytime

Comment: @DineshChandra - Which exception?  And what was the detail message?  See update to Answer too.